# how to convert a number to decimal formated value in c#?

Tags: c#

Which string format can convert this:

```
1 to 0.01
12 to 0.12
123 to 1.23
1234 to 12.34
12345 to 123.45
```

Inside my xamarin forms if a user types this number to an entry then it will automatically format that number. What is the string format of that?

For example: `Text={Binding Price,StringFormat='${0:F0}'}`

Comment: What do you mean - 1 to 0.01? Is that 1 to 0.01?

Comment: just divide :D 1/100 = 0.01

Comment: Divide by 100, that's all. Unless you have strings here and not numbers

Comment: I know that if divide by 100 then I will get this result,but I want the string formator which I can use inside the XAML in xamarin forms

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you just want division

```
var result = value / 100m;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

--

**Additional Resources**

[Division operator /](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-)

Comment: I know that if divide by 100 then I will get this result,but I want the string formator which I can use inside the XAML in xamarin forms

Answer (score 0):

You can divide by 100, as others are saying, followed by applying the desired [numeric formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

Answer (score 0):

Just as Michael Randall said above it's simple as that, in addiction you can check if it can be parsed first, something like this:

```
bool success = decimal.TryParse(value , out number);

if(success)
    var result = value / (decimal)100
else
    //Handle incorrect user input
```